# How to make an error in a Visual Studio post-build event make Visual Studio consider the build as failed?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

I was using Visual Studio 2015 when I noticed this issue, but I want a solution that will also work in 2017, 2019, and 2022 (and hopefully future versions as well)

I have a project with a post build event defined as follows to copy some dependencies into the build folder:

```
set OPENSSL_MANIFEST_ROOT=OpenSSL$(C_BITNESS).DllA
set OPENSSL_MANIFEST_DIR="$(TargetDir)\%OPENSSL_MANIFEST_ROOT%\"
set CURL_MANIFEST_ROOT=LibCurl$(C_BITNESS).DllA
set CURL_MANIFEST_DIR="$(TargetDir)\%CURL_MANIFEST_ROOT%\"
set COPY=xcopy /Y /D
set EXIT_ON_ERROR=if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

%COPY% "$(S_CURL_DIR)\lib\*.dll" %CURL_MANIFEST_DIR%
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_CURL_DIR)\lib\*.pdb" %CURL_MANIFEST_DIR%
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_CURL_BASE_DIR)\Manifests\%CURL_MANIFEST_ROOT%.manifest" %CURL_MANIFEST_DIR%
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_ZLIB_DIR)\lib\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_ZLIB_DIR)\lib\*.pdb" "$(TargetDir)"
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_OPENSSL_DIR)\bin\*.dll" %OPENSSL_MANIFEST_DIR%
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_OPENSSL_DIR)\bin\*.pdb" %OPENSSL_MANIFEST_DIR%
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(S_OPENSSL_BASE_DIR)\Manifests\%OPENSSL_MANIFEST_ROOT%.manifest" %OPENSSL_MANIFEST_DIR%
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
%COPY% "$(TargetDir)\%OPENSSL_MANIFEST_ROOT%\*" %CURL_MANIFEST_DIR%\%OPENSSL_MANIFEST_ROOT%\
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%

%COPY% "$(SIMBAENGINE_THIRDPARTY_DIR)\icu\$(S_ICU_V)\$(C_BLD_RELDIR)\lib\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
%EXIT_ON_ERROR%
```

I want the build to fail if any of the dependencies couldn't be copied, for any reason.

I just ran the build while forgetting to check out one of the dependencies from version control, and I got the following output

```
2>------ Build started: Project: AnglesViews, Configuration: debug_MTDLL x64 ------
2>     Creating library Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\AnglesViews.lib and object Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\AnglesViews.exp
2>  AnglesViews_vs2015.vcxproj -> C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\AnglesViews.dll
2>  AnglesViews_vs2015.vcxproj -> Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\AnglesViews.pdb (Full PDB)
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\libcURL\7.88.1_ssl3.0_zlib1.2.13_threaded_resolver\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\libcurl.dll
2>  1 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\libcURL\7.88.1_ssl3.0_zlib1.2.13_threaded_resolver\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\curl.pdb
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\libcURL\7.88.1_ssl3.0_zlib1.2.13_threaded_resolver\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\libcurl.pdb
2>  2 File(s) copied
2>  0 File(s) copied
2>  File not found - LibCurl64.DllA.manifest
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\zlib\1.2.13\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\zlibwapi.dll
2>  1 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\zlib\1.2.13\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\zlibwapi.pdb
2>  1 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\openssl\3.0\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\bin\libcrypto-3-x64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\openssl\3.0\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\bin\libssl-3-x64.dll
2>  2 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\openssl\3.0\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\bin\libcrypto-3-x64.pdb
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\openssl\3.0\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\bin\libssl-3-x64.pdb
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\openssl\3.0\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\bin\openssl.pdb
2>  3 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\openssl\3.0\Manifests\OpenSSL64.DllA.manifest
2>  1 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\\OpenSSL64.DllA\libcrypto-3-x64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\\OpenSSL64.DllA\libcrypto-3-x64.pdb
2>  C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\\OpenSSL64.DllA\libssl-3-x64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\\OpenSSL64.DllA\libssl-3-x64.pdb
2>  C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\\OpenSSL64.DllA\openssl.pdb
2>  C:\perforce\Drivers\DriverShared\AnglesViews\Maintenance\1.0\Bin\w2012r2\vs2015\debug64md\\OpenSSL64.DllA\OpenSSL64.DllA.manifest
2>  6 File(s) copied
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\icu\71.1.x\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\sbicudt71_64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\icu\71.1.x\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\sbicuin71_64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\icu\71.1.x\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\sbicuio71_64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\icu\71.1.x\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\sbicutu71_64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\icu\71.1.x\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\sbicuuc71_64.dll
2>  C:\perforce\ThirdParty\icu\71.1.x\w2012r2\vs2015\release64md\lib\sbtestplug_64.dll
2>  6 File(s) copied
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So even though the post-build event had the error `File not found - LibCurl64.DllA.manifest`, VS still considered the build a success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [exit /b 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618013/17034)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how variables (and ERRORLEVEL) work in batch files - which ultimately the build event content gets converted into.

The `%ERRORLEVEL%` in your `EXIT_ON_ERROR` variable will already be replaced (by 0 at that time) when you declare it. That is, this

```
set EXIT_ON_ERROR=if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

is already interpreted as

```
set EXIT_ON_ERROR=if 0 neq 0 exit /b 0
```

However, due to the way that this "works" it won't even work when you use `!ERRORLEVEL!` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (look those things up if you're intersted anyway).

You could do it like this, which is (arguably) less "noisy" anyway.

```
%COPY% "$(S_CURL_DIR)\lib\*.dll" %CURL_MANIFEST_DIR% || exit /b 1
...
```

Depending on the complexity of the tasks you need to perform (or the control you want to have over them - for example, only copy files if they do not exist in the "target directory"), you may want to ditch those events all together and rather use proper [targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2022) anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Your suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

Just return a non-zero exit code from your batch file, as indicated in VS:

[image]

Comment: but isn't that what %EXIT_ON_ERROR% is doing?